# Access value from function dispatch on component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm new to react.

I have a function, that need to refresh the state according with API request result on my component.

How can i access that value?

Code (Example):

LoginComponent.js

```
        class Login extends React.Component {
           constructor(props){
              super(props)
              this.state = {
                 username : '',
                 password : ''
              }
           }
           submit = (e) => {
              /* console.logging "Some response"*/
              console.log(this.props.doLogin(this.state))
           }
           render(){
              return (
                 <form onSubmit={this.submit}>/* some login element */</form>
              )
           }
        }

export default connect(null, {LoginAction})(Login);
```

LoginAction.js

```
export function doLogin(state){
   return dispatch => {
      return axios.post('login', state).then(res =>{

      return "Some response";

    })
   }
}
```

Comment: Just call the dispatch function in your axios thenable when the promise is resolved and have it update a bool in your redux store that says whether or not you're logged in

Comment: can you create an example? And login its just a example, its with more basics stuffs, for example feedback if something work or not

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

for example create axios.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

var instance = axios.create({
      baseURL: 'https://www.',
      timeout: 1000,
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer xxx'}
});
export default instance;
```

then in your another screen

```
import React from 'react';
import API from '../axios';


export default class Profile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      feedback: "",
      id: "",
      errors: {},
    };
}


  postComment = () => {
        API.post(`/new-comment`, {
          id: this.state.id,
          feedback: this.state.feedback,
        })
        .then(res => res.data)
        .then((response)=> {
          this.setState({
              feedback: '',
              error: response.error || null,
          })

        }).catch(error => {console.log(error), this.setState({ error});});
   }
```

Comment: i need use redux in that case.